# Finding the local maximum and minimum in each column-matlab

Tags: matlab, max

I want to find the local maximum and the minimum values between this 2 local maximums in every column of the image img_gauss. And then put them minimum values at 1 (white). Anyone knows how to do this in a easy way?

Below I have my code.  But I'm having some trouble, I try in every iteration (for each column) take the localization (locs) and then put them in the array  peaks_column, to have the peaks localization by column, but this error apears:

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in cropping_image_long (line 136)
        peaks_column(1:size(Intens_graph,1),x)=pks(:,1);

```
 pks= [];
 locs_column=zeros(20,size(img_gauss,2));
 locs= [];
 pks_column=zeros(20,size(img_gauss,2));
 for x = 1:size(img_gauss,2) % 2 = colunas x(colunas)
     % make a row wise intensity distribution graphic for each column
     Intens_graph(:,x)=img_gauss(size(img_gauss,1):-1:1,x);
     [pks,locs] = findpeaks(Intens_graph(:,x));%find the local maximum
     peaks_column(1:size(Intens_graph,1),x)=pks(:,1); %associate to each column
     locs_column(1:size(Intens_graph,1),x)=locs(:,1);

     BW = imregionalmin(Intens_graph);

 end
```

Comment: Could you post some sample data, please.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean with the minimums. Between two maximas there will always be one minimum. So i will find minimas with findpeaks.

```
% test data
data = rand(100);

% for saving minima and maxima positions
minimas = zeros(size(data));
for i = 1:size(data,2)
    column = data(:,i);
    [~,minis] = findpeaks(-column);
    % save the positions
    minimas(sub2ind(size(minimas),minis,repmat(i,length(minis),1))) = 1;
end
%generate result, paint all minimas with 1
result = data;
result(minimas==1) = 1;
```